# Subdomain CNAME pointing to IP on another server - how to auto-forward to subdir when using subdomain as URL?

Tags: redirect, ip, subdomain, cpanel, cname

We have a dedicated server that currently hosts our website directory on **xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/~website/website-dir**

We've forwarded a subdomain, **sub.othersite.com** on another shared hosting space, to the ip.

Effectively the **sub.othersite.com** still functions exactly the same as the ip, so **sub.othersite.com** brings up **/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi** just like the IP.

Is it possible to have **sub.othersite.com** automatically go to **sub.othersite.com/~website/website-dir** - but have the IP function as normal?

Answer (score 0):

Actually **/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi** this means either you just updated the IP or any DNS records. You have to wait maximum 72 hours to make it effective then you can check that.

You just need to set CNAME records for **sub.othersite.com** to **xxx.xxx.xx.xxx** and then after the DNS propagation time (up to 72 hours) you can browse **sub.othersite.com/~website/website-dir**. Because your sub.othersite.com can be used for xxx.xxx.xx.xxx and rest of the URL path you can use for that sub-domain.

I guess CNAME setting will help you that than redirecting. But if you redirect the subdomain to IP then still public will be able to see the IP not your subdomain or you can forward your subdomain to that IP url path by doing **Domain forward with masking**. So CNAME is better option.

Comment: We've been doing some tinkering. typing **sub.othersite.com** in the URL now auto forwards to  **sub.othersite.com/~website/website-dir**... But we want to hide the **~website/website-dir** part. eg we want the url to display **sub.othersite.com/page/** rather than **sub.othersite.com/~website/website-dir/page**. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: To do that you have to work in **.htaccess** on **sub.othersite.com**

Comment: We managed to find a solution through some httpd.conf and .htaccess trickery. Thanks for your help anyway!